# Multiplication in field Z5

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose we have $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2_5$

Solution to:
$2x+y=2$, $x+2y=0$ is $x=3$ and $y=1$

Question is - why there arent no more solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it similarly like you'd solve a regular system of linear equations.

$$2x+y\equiv 2\pmod{5}\iff y\equiv 2-2x\pmod{5}\tag{1}$$

$$x+2y\equiv 0\pmod{5}\stackrel{(1)}\iff x+2(2-2x)\equiv 0\pmod{5}$$

$$\iff x+4-4x\equiv -3x+4\equiv 2x-1\equiv 0\pmod{5}$$

$$\iff 2x\equiv 1\equiv 6\pmod{5}\stackrel{:2}\iff x\equiv 3\pmod{5}$$

By $(1)$ we get $y\equiv 2-2x\equiv 2-2\cdot 3\equiv 1\pmod{5}$.

Answer (score 1):

Just solve it directly. $2x+y = 2 \Rightarrow 2(x+2y) -3y= 2\Rightarrow -3y = 2\Rightarrow -3y + 5y = 2\Rightarrow 2y = 2\Rightarrow y = 1\Rightarrow 2x = 1\Rightarrow x = 3$

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for posting like this version.

[image]